# Changing Color of each face/vertex? OpenGL game project

Tags: opengl, rgb

I am working the the generic OpenGL game project which automatically creates 2 rotating cubes. I am trying to work out how to change each face/ vertex to a different colour. Currently it only enables you to change the colour of the whole cube.

Comment: What is 'it'? How are you currently setting the color?

Comment: currently everything is done automatically by Xcode. Using Xcode 5 if you make a openGL game project and run it you will see. My task is to change the color of each face using the generic project but is proving difficult

Comment: You should post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add color values to full data

```
GLfloat gCubeVertexData[324] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ,  your color
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,        1.0, 1.0, 0.5,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,        1.0, 0.5, 0.5,
....
};
```

In `setupGL` update to:

```
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 36, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 36, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 36, BUFFER_OFFSET(24));
```

Find the string `glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribNormal, "normal");`
and add:

```
glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribColor, "color");
```

and Shader.vsh:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 color;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

    colorVarying = color;// * diffuseColor * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

**But will be better if you will understand why you need to do those manipulations!**

Comment: @user3495815 ok, if understand, answer to me. What is `36` in `glVertexAttribPointer`?

Comment: i don't know exactly but 3 times 36 is 108 which is how many color values we need to store. so imagine its to do with that

Comment: @user3495815 no... we have position, normal and color per vertex - it's 9 floats, float is 4 bytes, then 9*4 = 36. Another words it's size of item in your data - stride. Read more: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml